# Defining an Observable in a Component

Tags: angular, angular7

I have the following service method in Angular 7:

```js
public getTopPosts(): Observable<Payload<PostResponse>> {

  return this.httpClient.get<Payload<PostResponse>>('/top-posts');

}
```

On the component I have:

```js
export class TopPostsComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: PostModel[] = [];

  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPosts();
  }

  getPosts() {

    this.postService.getTopPosts().subscribe((payload: Payload<PostResponse>) => {

      this.posts = payload.map((response: PostResponse) => { 
        return {
          id: response.id, 
          title: response.title
        };
      });

    });

  }
}
```

Shouldn't the posts variable in TopPostsComponent be:

```js
posts$: Observable<PostModel>[] = [];
```

But then I get the error:

```js
Type '{ id: number; title: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<PostModel>[]'.
Type '{ id: number; title: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<PostModel>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more."
```

When using:

```js
this.posts$ = payload.map((response: PostResponse) => { 
  return {
    id: response.id, 
    title: response.title
  };
});
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: The way you are subscribing to the `Observable` in your component, means that you are "getting" the data from the `Observable` so you can't store that as an `Observable` unless you instantiate a new one, or change the way you are accessing the service method (like a `pipe` or `map` instead of `subscribe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't initialize an observable with an array.

`posts$: Observable<PostModel>[] = [];`

Try using this:

```
posts$ = this.postService.getTopPosts().pipe(map(items => items.map(item => ({id: item.id, title: item.title}))));`
```

Of course, you could extract mapping to a different method to make it easier to read.
Or you could simply remove the mapping entirely (why copy id and title and not use them directly?).

```
export class TopPostsComponent implements OnInit {

  posts$: Observable<PostModel[]>;

  constructor(
    private postService: PostService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.posts$ = this.postService.getTopPosts().pipe(
      map(items => items.map(item => this.responseItemToModel(item)))
    );
  }

  private responseItemToModel(item: PostResponse): PostModel {
    return {
      id: item.id,
      title: item.title,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using map because Id and Title are only two of the properties I am mapping. I have a few more with more complex mapping.

Comment: Is there an advantage of using Observable<PostModel[]> over using only PostModel[]. I am asking this because in Angular Docs and searching Google I seed people using these two different options. I am not sure why.

Comment: @MiguelMoura well, you don't have to manage the subscription to the observable. Binding in the html directly to the observable using the `async` pipe tells angular to manage the subscription itself (when the component is in the DOM, etc.). For this simple example, it doesn't really matter, but using observables does allow composing them easily for more complex scenarios. It's also a bit more easier to turn your change detection strategy and push notifications to the bindings (so the app becomes a bit more efficient).